# Create a theme for a custom file type - Sublime

Tags: colors, themes

I wonder if someone could tell me, or link me to a place where someone can tell me (video, previous topic etc).

My question is how I create a simple theme that I can use in sublime. But the file type is not any famous one. I want to create a theme for a file type called .mcfunction - Currently, it runs plain text. So how do I do so that for example, numbers get green or some words highlight etc, I assume that is the easiest way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I develop data packs in .mcfunction and I use an intern package, just install Atom and install an mcfunction package